# Gradient appears behind navigation bar after app launch

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationbar

When my app is launching, as soon as the launch image is replaced by the initial view, a white gradient appears behind the navigation bar for one second (1st image) then disappears (2nd image).

[image]
[image]
I've tried to change the initial view to a different one to check if it's adding that gradient but it's still being added even with a plain `UITableViewController`.

Any clue or ideas on what might be causing this gradient during the transition from the launch image to the initial view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this was a bug in iOS and has been fixed in 7.1

Answer (score 0):

update the viewwillappear method to set the navigation bar translucent

set

navigationbar.translucent = NO

Comment: That does solve the gradient problem, but I don't want an opaque bar. Any clues on what's causing that to happen?

Comment: Try setting bar style